# Unable to add button to Custom List Item Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to add a Print Item button to the Forms (New, Edit, Display) of items in a Custom List. In order to achieve this I am using the following microsoft article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh500259(v%3Doffice.14).
I follow the steps, however the Button is not displayed. Attaching Screenshots of how it is set on Sharepoint designer  as reference

[image]

[image]

Do you have any ideas of what can be happening? Is there another way to add a print button the the Items Ribbon?

Answer (score 0):

The button would not be added to the Items ribbon. In fact, the button is added to the drop down menu of the list item, as the below picture shows:

[image]